# exception using external jar file algs4

Tags: java

I'm using the algs4 jar file from Sedgewick and Wayne 4th edition Algorithm books. I have added a reference to the jar file in may project, however, when I execute the program from cmd prompt, I get the following exception.

```
PS C:\Debug\Projects\Algorithms\bin> java.exe -classpath . BinarySearchClient
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/princeton/cs/algs4/In
        at BinarySearchClient.main(BinarySearchClient.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Can you please assist me to identify the cause of the exception. The jar file are located here: ***C:\Debug\Library\java***

The bin file of the program are here: ***C:\Debug\Projects\Algorithms\bin***